# Convert data class to map to test http GET response body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, testing, get

I'm trying to test a GET to get all the `StatusMapping` objects created, however, I'm not sure what's the best approach to test this.

The response is returning a map whereas I was expecting a list of StatusMapping objects instead.
Should I convert the requests to a map?

---

Here's the `Service` code:

```
fun getAll(): ResponseEntity<List<StatusMapping>> {
    return ResponseEntity<List<StatusMapping>>(statusMappingRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Here's the test

```
@Test
fun `Get all mappings created`() {
    val requests = listOf(
        StatusMapping("available", "available"),
        StatusMapping("unavailable", "unavailable")
    )
    requests.forEach { statusMappingService.createMapping(it.toStatusMappingRequest()) }

    val response = restTemplate.getForEntity(getRootUrl(), List::class.java)

    assertEquals(response.body, requests)
}
```

Here's the **error** that I'm getting:

```
Expected :[{source=available, target=available}, {source=unavailable, target=unavailable}]
Actual   :[StatusMapping(source=available, target=available), StatusMapping(source=unavailable, target=unavailable)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please start with replacing

```
val response = restTemplate.getForEntity(getRootUrl(), List::class.java)
```

with

```
val response = restTemplate.exchange(
        getRootUrl(),
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<StatusMapping>>() {})
```

Assuming that `restTemplate` is instance of `TestRestTemplate`

Comment: I did and now I'm getting `Expected:[]` on the test.

Should I also upgrade the service to return a type of  `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<StatusMapping>>` ?

Comment: Compare first entry in request with first entry in response, and total number of elements in both, that should suffice. BR

Comment: Nvm, I accidentally deleted a line of code.. Thank you for your help!